# Input HTML form data to a separate local html file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an html file that contains a form. When the form is submitted, I want the data from the form to be entered into the title element in a separate locally stored html file.

Below is my index.html and template.html files. The index.html file has a form with user entered data. I have a function that when the form is submitted, it retrieves the data from the form. I would like to then take this data and add it to a separate html file, template.html, then save the template.html file. I've looked at examples of load() and fetch() to retrieve the html document but I am seeing these are for external sites and just loads the data to a webpage. Is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function addElements() {
                let recipeTitle = document.getElementById('recipe_title')
                console.log(recipeTitle.value)

                return false;
            };
        </script>

        <form onsubmit="return addElements();" class="my-form">
            <div id="title">
                <p><b>Enter the name of the recipe:</b></p>
                <textarea rows="1" cols="70" id="recipe_title" name="recipe_title" form="recipe_form" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue">Some text here...</textarea>
            </div>

            <br><input class="submit-form" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <title>TITLE FROM INDEX.HTML FORM</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to have overlooked an important point about technical architecture: the Web is a client <-> server system. A web page cannot behave as a standalone application. however, you can use cookies, localestorage system...